# Failed to instantiate module [module name] due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I'm having an issue injecting `moment.js` into my module `myApp`. I have followed documentation from https://github.com/urish/angular-moment and https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-momentjs but to no avail. Reading other similar questions and answers, it's likely it is down to an incorrect synatx but I can't see it. Any ideas?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-moment.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

---

```
<main ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div class="container">             
        <section class="ng-view">

        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment']);

app.controller('transCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'moment', function($scope, $http, moment){
    $http.get('../json/transactions.json')
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.transaction = response.data.transactions;
    }, function(errResponse){
        alert('error');   
    });

    $scope.sortType     = 'transId'; // set the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
    $scope.searchTrans   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

    $scope.date = new moment();

    console.log($scope.date)

}]);
```

Comment: Did you try to inject angularMoment before ngRoute in your app?

Comment: You should inject angularMoment in the controller, not moment

Comment: @quirimmo Are you [sure about that?](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#use-in-controllerservicefactory)

Comment: Tried, same outcome

Comment: Nope sorry inside the controller you should inject just `moment` not `angularMoment`

Comment: Are you sure your script tags are actually reaching anything as I've created [a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LtjLq3jg/) with your code (mostly) and it works fine.

Comment: In the node documentation of the package, it injects it in this way. Have you tried it?
`angular.module('YOUR_APP', [
    'angular-momentjs',
    'controllers'
  ])`

Comment: Not use node, all through browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are including `moment.js` and `angular-moment` from `scripts` folder, you should download those two files into `scripts` folder and make sure your server serve for `scripts` folder as **static**(this can be confirmed by checking **network** tag of your browser).

the below example used online scripts and working fine.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment']);

app.controller('transCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'moment', function($scope, $http, moment) {
  $scope.date = new moment();

  console.log($scope.date)

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="scripts/moment.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.0/moment.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="scripts/angular-moment.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="transCtrl">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There must be something else wrong in my script. Still same error is showing. Anything else that it could possibly be? Im declaring the `<script>` tags in my `<head>` tag. Does it matter where my `transCtrl` controller is placed?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott no, that doesn't matter. have you confirmed all scripts been loaded successfully?

Comment: Any issue with it being on my localhost?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott that's the problem. what's your server side? nodejs? spring? .net?  you should check there.

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott simply check whether you `scripts` folder is at the same location with `index.html`. this may work.

Comment: Running localhost through Apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144663/discussion-between-patrick-mcdermott-and-pengyy).

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the `angular.min.js` script first. And add `moment.js` before `angular-moment.js`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-moment.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Made the changes and the problem persists

Comment: did you add `moment.js` before `angular-moment.js`

Comment: Yeah I did, really not sure why it's failing

Comment: When I remove the angularMoment injection, the application runs